# No errors after copying

Tags: compiling

While i am editing a .tex file , when i compiles it is showing error .

At that time when  copy the same code in to a different named .tex file , then new .tex file is showing no errors on compilation .

What may be the reason ?

And after undoing the code that caused error also compilation showing errors until i copies the code to some other new .tex file.

Error is as follows :

Runaway argument?
{\headcommand {\slideentry {9}{1}{18}{28/28 
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
 
                \par 
l.9 \begin{document}

Comment: I think you should add a Minimum Working Example (that reproduces the behaviour you are trying to understand) that could let us help you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Did you delete the generated files before recompiling? For example `.aux` but there are others. Make sure you clean up before recompiling if correcting code doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I didn't clean . i got now .

Comment: @cfr Then why correcting code works many times ? I mean i corrects code and compiles , it works fine most of times.

Comment: It depends if something problematic is written to one of the other files such that TeX keeps reading the error every compile. Usually, just correcting works OK. TeX gets through the compilation and anything generated is also corrected. But if there is a real issue in, say, the `.aux` file, it won't get re-written until you compile and you can't compile because TeX keeps reading the problematic code. So the only way to get TeX out of the loop is to (a) edit the generated file yourself or (b) delete it so TeX regenerates it. (b) is less work than (a). Hence, (b).

Comment: To whoever down-voted this question: please give new users some space. While this is not a great question, it is not terrible. Certainly much worse get up-voted regularly. This question is not a 'do-it-for-me' question; it makes reasonable efforts to explain (1) the problem, including a precise error message, (2) what has been tried to fix the problem, (3) why the problem is surprising in light of past experiences. It is tagged appropriately and has a somewhat useful subject line. It could certainly be improved but down-voting is excessive in my opinion.